# Serverless first deploy error occured: HelloLogGroup - User

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

I want to test deploy serverless project using default serverless template, but i got this error

```
 An error occurred: HelloLogGroup - User: arn:aws:iam::346468483688:user/crm_development is not authorized to perform: logs:DescribeLogGroups on resource: arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:346468483688:log-group::log-stream: (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: cb3894c8-aaca-400b-9862-a610e0cbffc2).
```

Comment: Does it have enough permissions? the error is complaining about "Access"

Comment: did you configured the permissions on the yaml? can you share your yaml

Answer (score 0):

This is probably that you are missing some provider configuration to let CloudFormation deal with the log versioning and retention. I suggest you to add this following configurations at the provider section of the serverless.yml file:

```yaml
provider:
  ...
  logRetentionInDays: 14
  versionFunctions: true
  ...
```

In additional, you can check it out on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=623472 discussion.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's related to ApiGateway permissions
solved by adding permission to role
iam-> roles -> selected relevant **code build** role-> policies -> attach policy -> select API gateway -> read + write

Comment: Have no API gateway policy.

Answer (score -2):

This is a permissions error.  The user that you are using to deploy the serverless project does not have permissions to `logs:DescribeLogGroups`.

To resolve this issue you'll need to give the user that is deploying the service permissions to `logs:DescribeLogGroups` on resource `arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:346468483688:log-group::log-stream:`